# Is every group of odd order isomorphic to a subgroup of $A_n$ for some $n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Is every group of odd order isomorphic to a subgroup of $A_n$ for some $n$?

If not, what is a counterexample; if so, how can I prove it?

Hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Every finite group is, so in particular those of odd order.

Answer (score 3):

Every finite group is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$. Now take $G$ a subgroup of odd order included in $S_n$. Let $g\in G\subseteq S_n$, write its unique decomposition into cycles :

$$g=c_1...c_r\text{ then } \epsilon(g)=\epsilon(c_1)...\epsilon(c_r) $$

Now you know how to compute the signature of a cycle, namely if $c$ is a cycle of length $l$ then $\epsilon(c)=(-1)^{l+1}$.

Hence :

$$\epsilon(g)=(-1)^{(l_1+1)+...+(l_r+1)} $$

Where $l_i$ is the length of $c_i$. To finish, I claim that $l_i$ must be odd because you know that $o(c_i)=l_i$ and (all $c_i$'s are commuting) $o(g)=ppcm(o(c_1),...,o(c_r))=ppcm(l_1,...,l_r)$ so if one of the $l_i$'s were even so would be $o(g)$ and (by Lagrange's theorem) so would be $|G|$. Hence $(l_i+1)$ is always even and $\epsilon(g)=1$. This means that $G\subseteq Ker(\epsilon)=A_n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

1. Say, left multiplication by any element $g$ of a finite group $G$ permutes the elements of $G$ (and by uniqueness of the identity element this permutation is distinct for each element $g$), so we can always regard $G$ as a subgroup of $S_G \cong S_{\# G}$.
2. For any $m$ there is an injective homomorphism $S_m \hookrightarrow A_{m + 2}$.

**Remark** Putting these facts together gives us an upper bound on the $n$ required: Every finite group $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $A_{\#G + 2}$.

Comment: Actually $S_m$ embeds into $A_{m+2}$ but not in $A_{m+1}$, unless $m = 1$.

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen Oops, you're right, I've corrected the answer, and thanks for the catch. (I remember that there are several nice proofs of the nonembedding result in an old question on Math Overflow, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/65083/an-easy-proof-that-sn-does-not-embed-into-an1 .)